# How to show an custom event in ATTRIBUTION in Firebase Analytics without ad network?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We print dynamic links as an QR code on stickers in many places. Each sticker has different campaign in it. We would like to analysis which sticker (which spot) has the best performance of registration. There's an event when user complete the sign up process, named as "register".

The event is working as expected. It's shown in EVET. And we mark it as conversion.

[image]

But we couldn't see the register event shown in ATTRIBUTION. There's only one event, first_open, which is generated by firebase-analytics itself.

[image]

Our goal is to see **which source contributes the most with register event**, like first_open. Do we have to use an ad network to accomplish this feature ?

[image]

Dynamic links is :
https://myappapi.app.goo.gl/?link=http://our.web.site&apn=our.app.name&st=testRegTitle&sd=testRegDescription&si=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/some_code_here&**utm_source**=testRegSource&**utm_medium**=testRegMedium&**utm_campaign**=testRegCampaign

Comment: Does your dynamic link have any "utm_" params like utm_campaign? If an app is opened with such link, and a conversion event occurs, it will be attributed to the campaign.

Comment: @adbitx we do, please see revise as above, thank you :)

Comment: do you have any conversion events that might occur after the app is opened (like in app purchase, ecommerce_purchase, etc.). I saw only 1 register event that is marked as conversion and it is attributed correctly in the second picture (testRegSource as in utm_source). If, let's say someone clicks on your link to open the app and register, then the campaign event will be attributed to that conversion event.

Comment: Thank you for your time looking into this mystery. Register event is the only event we set so far. The second picture is first_open event in ATTRIBUTION. The third one shows the result of clicking first_event in ATTRIBUTION. No sight of register event.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I didn't look carefully. I thought the 3rd picture shows attribution to register event, but it is about first_open. Since there is only 1 register event recorded, it might not be logged after the dynamic link was clicked. Are you sure that the event is logged at the correct moment? It looks like there are more first_open than register so it's hard to tell the problems.

Comment: It just worked after a week later .. Thank you @adbitx for looking into it :)